# Project Euler 34 Help [Python]

Tags: python

The problem is:

145 is a curious number, as 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145.

Find the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorial of their digits.

Note: as 1! = 1 and 2! = 2 are not sums they are not included.

```
# Project Euler Problem 34
def factorial(num):
    """Factorial"""
    product = num
    for i in range(2, num):
        product *= i
    return product

def check_sum(number):
    list_digits = list(str(number))
    check_sum = 0
    for digit in list_digits:
        check_sum += factorial(int(digit))
    if check_sum == number:
        return True

def find_final_sum():
    """Find the sum of all the numbers."""
    final_list = []
    final_sum = 0
    counter = 3
    while counter < 200000:
        if check_sum(counter):
            final_list.append(counter)
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter += 1

    for j in final_list:
        final_sum += j
    print(final_sum)

find_final_sum()
```

I defined a function to find factorials.
Then I defined a function to check if a number is equal to the sum of the factorials of its digits.
Finally, I check numbers from 3 to 200000. If a number works, I put it in a list.
At the end, I sum up the list and print it.

This code only gives me 145 as the answer. I can't see what I'm doing wrong, could anyone help?

I'm not trying to post a solution to the Euler problem.

Comment: You have a variable and a function with the same name (final_sum)

Comment: There are a finite amount of curious numbers. See [Factorion: Upper Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorion#Upper_bound)

Comment: The point of Project Euler is to not use brute force.

Comment: Note that a) you can table your factorial (calculate the factorials of 0-9 into a list or even dictionary of digit -> int, b) exit early `if check_sum > number`, c) `return check_sum == number`; d) use `for counter in range(3, 200000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factorial function is incorrect as it falsely calculates `0!` as `0`. You can fix it like this:

```
def factorial(num):
    """Factorial"""
    if num < 2:
        return 1
    ...
```

then your code will print `40730`.

PS: The only other curious number in your range is 40585.

Comment: Thanks so much! So I only need to check numbers up to like 50000?

Comment: Or he could have used `math.factorial()`.

Comment: I don't know about Project Euler at all; are you forbidden to use built-in methods? Also, there can be other curious numbers beyond 200,000.

Comment: @Reti43 I didn't know there was a math.factorial(). I'll try it out now.

Comment: I have not seen any such restriction. In fact, I've seen many people choose languages for their built-in capabilities, e.g. Python's arbitrary integer precision. To clarify on my comment, it was just another suggestion on top of explaining his mistake. Reinventing the wheel is a great way of learning the algorithm, along with common mistakes one could make, such as the one the OP made.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same name for func and var. But that wasn't the problem. The problem was the function factorial

```
import math

def check_sum(number):
    list_digits = list(str(number))
    check_sum = sum([math.factorial(int(digit)) for digit in list_digits])
    return check_sum == number

def final_sum(counter_min=3, counter_max=200000):
    """Find the sum of all the numbers."""
    final_sum = 0
    for counter in xrange(counter_min, counter_max):
        if check_sum(counter):
             final_sum += counter
    return final_sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(final_sum())
```

Comment: Yes. I just tried it with math.factorial(). My original factorial function could not calculate 0! correctly.

Comment: Is xrange() a python2 function? I use python3

Comment: Python3 doesn't have xrange(). In python3 u can use range()

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks 145, 154, 415, 451, 514 and 541. This means that you calculate the same factorial sum 6 times. This repetition increases as you go to more digits. Try just calculating the unique digit combinations and test to see if the sum contains these digits in any order.

```
import math
def compare_digits( val, arr, nesting_depth ):
  digits = [int(d) for d in str(val)]
  digits.sort()
  return arr[0:sz] == digits

f = [math.factorial(i) for i in range(10)]
idx = [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ]
for idx[0] in range(10):
  for idx[1] in range(idx[0], 10):
    sum = f[idx[0]] + f[idx[1]]
    if compare_digits( sum, idx, 2 ):
      total += sum
    for idx[2] in range(idx[1], 10):
      sum = f[idx[0]] + f[idx[1]] + f[idx[2]]
      if compare_digits( sum, idx, 3 ):
        total += sum
      # for idx[3] etc.
```

Note that array idx is always sorted up to the loop nesting depth.